# Check If your Rest API is called or not in certain time interval

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Consider there are 2 Rest APIs implemented using Java and spring .

One to raise a request(https://example.com/some-service/Requests)(1st API)(our application consumes),It does some processing at the back end but it does not return me the actual result and instead returns me success response.

The needed response to my request takes some time for example 13 mins and this actual response is sent through another API which our application exposes, for example(<ourApplication.com/notifyRaisedRequests>)(2nd API).

I want to write the code in java such that response from 2nd API should not take more than 13 mins after I raise request using 1st API.If more than 13 mins execute failure part and if less than 13 mins execute success part of code

How can this be achieved using Spring boot,Java.There should be someway to keep checking in spring boot that whether 2nd API was called or not within the time interval(13mins). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you make the request, write a record into the DB with the time. Then have a @Scheduled component which checks the outstanding requests once per minute (say) and takes the appropriate error action. Your implementation of the notify endpoint will do the success action.

Comment: can you help me understand how can i check the outstanding requests here(2nd API calls)

Comment: Read the records that you put in the DB when you made the requests, and compare the time you recorded with the current time.

Comment: sorry, i could not understand your answer clearly.There are 2 parts in your answer one error action which is handled by Scheduled component and success action handled by notify endpoint.Consider notification came in 5 mins.success part will be executed how do you make error action not to be taken because it is running independently.In other words how do you tell @scheduled component that notify endpoint was hit and stop calculating the time

Comment: I solved this problem by maintaining a Hashmap. Whenever you make a call to 1st API , Hashmap will have a entry and when response is received through second API , it will delete that entry in hashmap and call checktimeout() method and this methods job is to keep checking every minute (specific interval) if entry exists in Hashmap or not? If exists second api response is not received yet or else response received and also it checks whether 13 minute time interval crossed or not if crossed and entry still exists it will take failure workflow.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestions. Appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really specific to Java, it sounds more like an architectural concern.

- A user or a process requests resource X by calling the first api
- An "OK" (200) response is returned
- A user or a process requests resource Y (notify) by calling the second api
- If less than Z amount of time has passed between the call to Y and the call to X then send response A; otherwise send response B

One way to tackle this, as suggested in the comments, is to use a database to keep a unique record with a timestamp for each request to the fist api (X). When the second api (Y) is called, it's straghtforward: get the difference in time and act accordingly.

As for generating a unique identifier for each request to the first api, depending on where the record is stored you could do different things but my suggestion would be to keep it really simple and use a random uuid: `UUID.randomUUID()`.

This implies that the response the first api sends back to whatever requested it will have that same uuid in it somewhere since this is necessary for the second api.

For example:

request to api X is received by a spring rest controller (or similar). Somewhere in there (i.e. service layer called by the controller) a unique identifier will be created and a record will be saved in the database. This unique identifier must be returned in the response.

request to api Y is made with the uuid returned in the X's response. This can then be used to recover more information that was saved in the database for that request (such as the timestamp).

EDIT

As per more indications in the comments, three components are needed: a rest controller, a service for data storage / retrieval and a scheduler.

1. A call is made to first api via controller which uses the service to store information specific to that request. The controller's response returns the uuid to the user for reference.
2. A scheduler uses that same service to periodically check if the second call has been made or not and decides what to do based on the amount of time lapsed.
3. If a second call is made, it also uses the same service to save the relevant data and/or delete old records as necessary.

Comment: We have to assume that there's some key returned from /Requests which is also sent in the request to /notifyRaisedRequests

Comment: correct, I forgot to write the assumption in my answer. I've updated it, thanks for pointing ti out.

Comment: Consider second api took very long time(40 mins) then end user has to wait till 40 mins to get the error response which is performance issue.Requirement here is,If time between calling First API and second API takes more than 13 mins send error response immediately .I feel it may not be correct to have time difference calculation to be put after second API ,notify is called.

Comment: In that case, you can keep track of the calls to the second api in the same way (with the uuid and a record in a database somewhere) and make a batch job / scheduler to check times between calls. I'll update the answer later.

Comment: @WilliamBurnham, again we are waiting till the second API call is made right?if 13 min time interval crosses we need not have to care whether second API call is made or not.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. You can do whatever you need to do with a scheduler after the first call has been made. If there is no record of the second call after Z minutes (scheduler checking for a record once every minute for example) then you don't waste time with any unnecessary operations.

Answer (score 0):

The code which raises the request:

```
   Response r = post("/Requests");
   db.insert(r.getUniqueId(), now);
```

The code which receives the notification:

```
void listener(NotificationRequest r) {
   db.delete(r.getUniqueId());
   // do the success action
}
```

The code which runs periodically checking the outstanding requests:

```
for (DbRecord r: db.selectAllRecords()) {
   if (r.time - now > 15 minutes) {
     db.delete(r.id);
     // do the failure action
   }
}
```

This is all pseudocode obviously.

Comment: sorry, our application does not have database .It simply does processing the requests .The other idea may be to put this in Hashmaps but i should make it accessible in different classes like in RaiseRequest.java,NotifyRequest.java(success scenario) and RequestTimeOut.java(failure scenario) .This may bring some more problems as i am making maps accessible application wide

Comment: Without a persistent store of some sort your service won't be robust across restarts. The failure action may never occur for a request which was received before the restart and later timed out. Your current architecture is at odds with your requirements,

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you have to analyze your code and API calls first. Exactly where it is consuming more time like while fetching the data from DB(In this case you need to optimize your DB query)or processing the records from client/DB or etc..

You can use any monitoring tool present in the market, for the first analysis.You will get a idea of your API calls, method execution time, thread dump etc...

This link gives some tool names.
https://geekflare.com/api-monitoring-tools/

If you are using spring, then use the spring build library to get the metrics of the application.

Use the below link for more reference::

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: I don't think the OP controls that service.